# Problema al comparar Contraseña Cifrada en SQL Server utilizando SHA2_256 en Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, ssms, sha256

Estoy enfrentando un problema al intentar comparar contraseñas cifradas utilizando la función `HASHBYTES` en SQL Server, específicamente utilizando el algoritmo `SHA2_256`. Mi objetivo es validar el acceso de un usuario a través de un Stored Procedure que compara el nombre de usuario y contraseña proporcionados con la almacenada en la base de datos.

Código de la creación de tablas:

```sql
-- Crear tabla Rol_Usuario
CREATE TABLE ROL_USUARIO (
    [ID Rol Usuario] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    NombreRol NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DescripcionRol NVARCHAR(1020) NOT NULL,
    Nivel_Acceso INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY([ID Rol Usuario])
);
GO

-- Crear tabla Usuario
CREATE TABLE USUARIO (
    ID_Empleado INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    NombreUsuario NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Contrasenia VARBINARY(64) NOT NULL,
    [ID Rol] INT NOT NULL,
    Estado NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_Empleado),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_Empleado) REFERENCES EMPLEADO([ID Empleado]),
    FOREIGN KEY([ID Rol]) REFERENCES ROL_USUARIO([ID Rol Usuario])
);
GO
```

Código de la inserción de datos de prueba:

```sql
-- Insertar datos en la tabla ROL_USUARIO
INSERT INTO ROL_USUARIO (NombreRol, DescripcionRol, Nivel_Acceso)
VALUES 
  ('Administrador', 'Rol con acceso total al sistema', 100),
  ('Supervisor', 'Rol con privilegios de supervisión', 75),
  ('Analista', 'Rol con acceso a funciones analíticas', 50),
  ('Operador', 'Rol con funciones operativas básicas', 25);
GO

-- Insertar datos en la tabla USUARIO
INSERT INTO USUARIO (NombreUsuario, Contrasenia, [ID Rol], Estado)
VALUES 
  ('admin', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'admin123'), 1, 'Habilitado'),
  ('supervisor1', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'supervisor123'), 2, 'Habilitado'),
  ('analista1', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'analista123'), 3, 'Habilitado'),
  ('operador1', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'operador123'), 4, 'Habilitado'),
  ('supervisor2', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'supervisor456'), 2, 'Habilitado'),
  ('analista2', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'analista456'), 3, 'Deshabilitado'),
  ('operador2', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'operador456'), 4, 'Habilitado'),
  ('supervisor3', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'supervisor789'), 2, 'Habilitado'),
  ('analista3', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'analista789'), 3, 'Habilitado'),
  ('operador3', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'operador789'), 4, 'Habilitado');
GO
```

Código del Stored Procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_VerificarAcceso
    @NombreUsuario NVARCHAR(255),
    @Contrasenia NVARCHAR(255),
    @Estado NVARCHAR(255) = 'Habilitado'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NivelAcceso INT;

    SELECT @NivelAcceso = R.Nivel_Acceso
    FROM USUARIO U
    INNER JOIN ROL_USUARIO R ON U.[ID Rol] = R.[ID Rol Usuario]
    WHERE U.NombreUsuario = @NombreUsuario AND U.Contrasenia = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Contrasenia) AND Estado = @Estado;

    SELECT @NivelAcceso AS Nivel_Acceso;

    RETURN;
END;
```

Intente hacerlo sin variables, así:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM USUARIO
WHERE NombreUsuario = 'admin' AND Contrasenia = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'admin123');
```

Y funcionó pero luego fui agregando las variables una por una hasta que use la variable `@Contrasenia` y ya no funcionaba como debía:

```sql
DECLARE @NivelAcceso INT;
DECLARE @Contrasenia NVARCHAR(10);
SELECT @Contrasenia = 'admin123';
SELECT @NivelAcceso = R.Nivel_Acceso
FROM USUARIO U
INNER JOIN ROL_USUARIO R ON U.[ID Rol] = R.[ID Rol Usuario]
WHERE U.NombreUsuario = 'admin' AND U.Contrasenia = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Contrasenia) AND Estado = 'Habilitado';
SELECT @NivelAcceso AS Nivel_Acceso;
PRINT 'Variables: ';
PRINT 'Nivel Acceso: ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @NivelAcceso);
PRINT 'Contraseña: ' + @Contrasenia;
```

Esto es lo que yo esperaba obtener, tal como lo hacía sin la variable `@Contrasenia`:

```sql
Nivel_Acceso
------------
100

(1 row affected)

Variables: 
Nivel Acceso: 100
Contraseña: admin123
```

Pero esto era lo que obtenía justo luego de aplicar el uso de dicha variable:

```sql
Nivel_Acceso
------------
NULL

(1 row affected)

Variables: 
 
Contraseña: admin123
```

*PD: Cabe mencionar que configuré el SSMS para que todos los resultados me los mostrara por medio de mensajes.*

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tu problema se debe a diferencias de Collation o a los diferentes tipos de datos utilizados para la generación de los hash

El hash generado por HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'admin123') (utilizado en el Insert de datos de prueba) es distinto al generado por:

```
DECLARE @Contrasenia NVARCHAR(10);
HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Contrasenia)

select contrasenia from usuario where nombreusuario = 'admin'
select HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Contrasenia)
```

Los resultados para las consultas son distintos

Y para finalizar, el motivo de esta diferencia de hash se debe a que el tipo de dato de 'admin123' es VARCHAR y la variable que utilizas para la contraseña ingresada para validar es NVARCHAR

- VARCHAR utiliza 1 byte por caracter
- NVARCHAR utiliza 2 bytes por caracter

por lo tanto al utilizar HASHBYTES (que genera el hash en base a los bytes del texto o variable que indiques) son totalmente distintos.

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, te damos la bienvenida al sitio y gracias por la respuesta. Por favor, completa el [tour] y así aprenderás más sobre la comunidad y recibirás tu primera medalla en el sitio.